# How to ignore certificate verification in react js

Tags: reactjs, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have created a responsive react app. When it executes on desktop it works well(be it in collapsed view or full view).
But when I run it specifically on mobile, the react page loads but it does not make calls to the backend server.

**If it can be due to SSL Certificate, can someone please suggest me how can I make react app not to verify the SSL certificate and make successful backend calls?**

Thank you!

Comment: React has no interaction with the actual connections, this is managed by the browser. An ssl error would show in your browser and is an unlikely culprit.

Comment: @Deadron thank you, where can I read more thoroughly about it as "react does not interact with actual connections". If not SSL what else can be the issue here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn

Comment: @Deadron can you please suggest, what can be the issue if react is not able to make calls to the server from mobile but from desktop?